# Why is this string returning NULL? (Binary conversion)

Tags: objective-c, binary, nsmutablestring

I am trying to separate the last four digits of an 8bit binary string. In order to do this I have tried to create a new string and appendFormat each of the last four digits of the original string. The only problem is this new string always returns NULL when I know it shouldn't be. Anyone have an idea about what I'm doing wrong?

```
NSMutableString *str = @"01110001;

unsigned short zero = [str characterAtIndex:0]-48;
unsigned short one = [str characterAtIndex:1]-48;
unsigned short two = [str characterAtIndex:2]-48;
unsigned short three = [str characterAtIndex:3]-48;
unsigned short four = [str characterAtIndex:4]-48;
unsigned short five = [str characterAtIndex:5]-48;
unsigned short six = [str characterAtIndex:6]-48;
unsigned short seven = [str characterAtIndex:7]-48;

NSMutableString *newString;
[newString appendFormat:@"%d%d%d%d",four, five, six, seven];
NSLog(@"NEWSTRING:%@", newString);
```

Alternatively, is there a better way to get just the last four digits of the original string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the methods of `NSString`:

```
NSString *str = @"01110001";
NSString *lastFour = [str substringFromIndex:str.length - 4];
```

This code assumes that `str` has at least 4 characters. It will give you the last four no matter how long the string is.

Update to explain the original problem.

You were getting nil because you never initialized `newString`. It is `nil` and you call `appendFormat:` on the `nil` value which does nothing.

It would have worked if you did:

```
NSMutableString *newString = [NSMutableString string];
```

However, neither of your strings need to be mutable.

You should have done:

```
NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d%d%d",four, five, six, seven];
```

Of course, as the beginning of my answer shows, none of that was needed anyway.